# I2C Issues - SCL is stuck high

Tags: i2c

I am working on a custom carrier board using a TI microcontroller as the master and an ADC IC as the slave. It appears that sometimes SCL will stay high when it shouldn't, almost like the master releases it. We only get this fault condition on a reset of the MCU (or total system power cycle) but it does not happen every time, maybe one out of ten on average.

Data transfer will be fine most of the time, until one of the unlucky resets causes the issues. You can see in the image below that after the address byte is sent SCL just goes high after a few clock pulses. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Is it possible the MCU is busy, servicing interrupts perhaps?  I see you appear to have transitions on the data line even though no clocks are going out.  Are those from the master or slave?  Do you have a proper scope that can look at your clock line to make sure the transitions are clean?

Comment: @evildemonic Where did you found those transitions on data line? What I see is data line staying low, just like in the first byte of the previous transmission. What is strange, however, is that the analyzer did not recognize three SCL pulses after ACK as valid clock pulses (there are no arrows on rising edges)

Comment: You need to provide more data if you want meaningful help. Like, is hardware I2C used by MCU or bit banging? What is the misterious "ADC IC"? Do you have other slaves on a bus?

Comment: @Maple The green and red dots.

Comment: @evildemonic the green and red dots are quite normal Start and Stop conditions

Comment: @Maple Ok, I see that now, thank you.  We will need more information to diagnose this further.  A datasheet for the ADC and proper scope traces to inspect signals would be a big help.

Comment: @Maple the arrows on the clock edges appear to show those interpreted as part of a transfer word by the protocol decoder.  The last set of clocks are insufficient in number for a complete word, so they aren't recognized by the protocol decoder.

Answer (score 7):

From recent comments:

> the microprocessor does return an arbitration lost flag

Thanks, that is *vital* new info and deserves to be added to the question. So does this info:

> I discovered this problem happens when the reset is pressed during activity on SDA. If the reset is pressed while SDA is high, the bus does not get messed up.

Based on the new info, I believe your problem is a duplicate of previous question "[I2C bus occupied](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/391839/101852)".

Your expectation that "*I would think the MCU would come back up in a known good state with I2C initialized*" is not true, because the MCU does not control the state of *all* devices on the I2C bus. The I2C Master only knows and controls its own state. It relies on other devices following the I2C protocol, to infer *their* state. Resetting only *some* devices on the bus can result in a mismatch between the internal states of the various devices on the bus, and lead to problems like yours.

When they restart, I2C Masters can be affected when they see that an I2C Slave is pulling SDA low, waiting for clock pulses from the I2C Master (which the Master won't send, as it was just reset) so the Slave waits, still pulling SDA low.

For example: After restarting, some I2C Masters (e.g. MCU), before they start the I2C SCL clock, will check the SDA signal. In your case, it sees that SDA is *already low*. This state can be interpreted as there being another I2C Master device driving the bus. Actually the cause of SDA being low is the I2C Slave, which was in mid-transmission before the MCU was reset. However now the Slave isn't receiving SCL pulses from the I2C Master and so it cannot complete its transmission. Most I2C Slaves don't timeout and release SDA in that situation, although a few do.

The fixes in the answer to the [above linked question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/391839/101852) would apply here e.g. pulsing SCL manually, until the I2C Slave releases SDA, or resetting the I2C Slave (via a reset pin or local power switch to the I2C Slave(s)). Then restart I2C on the Master. The I2C master will see that SDA is no longer being held low, and so it will start to drive SCL again, as it won't be confused that there is another I2C Master on the bus.

Comment: I believe sending Stop condition first thing after wake up should take most slaves out of stupor. Since protocol defines that it should be expected at any time, regardless of the state of the I2C state machine

Comment: @Maple A STOP condition is the master raising (releasing) SDA while SCL is stable high. However, the slave cannot see this because it is holding SDA low. This is why the master must first clock SCL enough times to get the slave to stop trying to send data.

Comment: @DoxyLover Ah, yes. Didn't think this through.

Answer (score 2):

Look closer: SDA is **low**.

This is the "arbitration lost" case, where the master wants to put a "1" on the bus but reads back a zero. In I²C terms, this would mean there is *another* master on the bus, an thus the original master ceases toggeling the SCL line.

Now you will have to look at *why* the ADC (or something else in on your I²C bus) exibits this behaviour - but that is a different and much more interesting question.

Comment: This is "read" transmission. Whatever is on the bus is interpreted as input by master, therefore there cannot be any arbitration loss. See previous transmission  for example, 0 is returned as first two bytes

Comment: Actually, the microprocessor does return an arbitration lost flag, however the ADC can only act as a slave so I don't think its the typical arb. lost case. I discovered this problem happens when the reset is pressed during activity on SDA. If the reset is pressed while SDA is high, the bus does not get messed up. This explains why the problem seems random and sporadic. But why would a reset during bus activity cause this problem? I would think the MCU would come back up in a known good state with I2C initialized and ready to go.

Comment: I don't know what you call "typical arbitration lost case". There is only one arbitration lost condition, and it is when sender detects low level while trying to transmit high level. In your screenshot the error happens during first _received_ byte, when anything on the SDA is valid. UNLESS the error actually happened during address transmission and it simply took MCU some time to react. This is in fact possible, if slave continues transmission when MCU comes out of reset

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of the MCU being reset during a bus transaction and essentially forgetting what it was doing. The slave ADC has no idea the MCU was reset and still thinks they are communicating and it is waiting for the MCU to respond with more clock pulses. However since the MCU lost power it does not know where it left off, meanwhile its seeing the SDA line low and thinks there is arbitration. So it is an issue of the slave waiting to send all of its data, but the MCU doesn't know that, so actually it is the mcu's fault.

This white paper describes this completely. [Link](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/54305147357414AN686_0.pdf)

Comment: Oh, I see that you wrote that while I was writing my longer explanation. It's the same conclusion as mine :-)

Comment: This is a good explanation of the problem without getting all bogged down in overly technical terminology.